# CSS 3 Text Shadow with Outline

Tags: html, css

I have font called MyriadPro-BoldIt, I used that on photoshop to create a text design like below.

[image]

I tried to add this style using css by adding below codes to the same font which I converted to web fonts before

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
color: white;
text-shadow:3px 3px 0 #000,-1px -1px 0 #000, 1px -1px 0 #000,-1px 1px 0 #000,1px 1px 0 #000;
```

but it is not giving same results. Anyone knows how to create this kind of letters using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do something like this.

```
h1 {
    font-size: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff,
            -1px 1px 0 #fff, 3px 3px 5px #333;
}​
```

[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THWLL/)

Comment: You can adjust the values to get the desired effect. You can accept the answer if it has helped you :)

Comment: IE 9 not working this, do you know about
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#0000FF,direction=45);
to add for ie 9

Answer (score 1):

have you tried simply:

```
  color: black;
text-shadow:
  2px 2px 0 white,
  3px 3px 0 gray;
```

you have to tune coordonates and font-size in order to have something looking fine.
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/rnmdv/

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a demo that works well: http://jsfiddle.net/XLRbQ/

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: black;
    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 5px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: white;
    text-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #000;
```

And also a tutorial CSS-Tricks: http://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/